Is this buck/boost layout good?
I have this PCB layout with two TPS631011 buck/boost converters. I just wanted to know, whather thelLayout is good or if there is anything I should change before manufacturing this board.



Two layer board?

The ground "plane" is so cut-up by various traces in some spots that it cannot do its job. The bottom layer in this case should have only very short jumpers that are used to cross top layer traces where it's not possible to otherwise deconflict them. If you can post the project on github it'd be easier to edit it and show how to alter it to make it better.

Thanks for the reply! I will try to post the design on gitHub today and I am going to fix the Groundplane as much as I can...
